# Grails paginate not working

Tags: java, grails

I have this list code in my controller that uses dynamic finders

```
def listPurchaseRequest(Integer max){
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 5, 100)

    def purchaseRequestList = PurchaseRequest.list (params)     
    if ( params.query) {
        purchaseRequestList = PurchaseRequest.findAllByRequestByLikeOrRequestNumberLike("%${params.query}%", "%${params.query}%", params)
    }

    [purchaseRequestInstanceList: purchaseRequestList,
     purchaseRequestInstanceTotal: //this]
}
```

My search and list is working except for my pagination.

```
<g:paginate total="${purchaseRequestInstanceTotal}" params="${params}" maxsteps="3" prev="&laquo;" next="&raquo;" />
```

if i use `purchaseRequestList.totalCount` it works with the default list but when the result is displayed after i search it gives me a `Exception evaluating property 'totalCount' for java.util.ArrayList, Reason: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: totalCount for class: rms.PurchaseRequest` error

if i use `purchaseRequestList.count()` it gives me this `Could not find which method count() to invoke from this list: public java.lang.Number java.util.Collection#count(groovy.lang.Closure) public java.lang.Number java.util.Collection#count(java.lang.Object)` error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [`CountBy*`](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/countBy.html) methods for the search. Try this

```
def listPurchaseRequest(Integer max){
    params.max = Math.min(max ?: 5, 100)

    def purchaseRequestList, count  

    if (params.query) {
        purchaseRequestList = PurchaseRequest.findAllByRequestByLikeOrRequestNumberLike("%${params.query}%", "%${params.query}%", params)
        count = PurchaseRequest.countByRequestByLikeOrRequestNumberLike("%${params.query}%", "%${params.query}%")
    } else {
        purchaseRequestList = PurchaseRequest.list (params)
        count = purchaseRequestList.totalCount
    }

    [purchaseRequestInstanceList: purchaseRequestList,
     purchaseRequestInstanceTotal: count]
}
```

FYI, I moved the `.list()` into an `else` clause to save you calling both `list` and `findBy` when `params.query` is set.